# What is the detail namespace commonly used for

Tags: c++, namespaces

In some of the larger projects or libraries (e.g. Eigen), you can see namespaces like `internal` or `detail`. I understand what is `internal` good for, but what is `detail` commonly used for? Is there any common convention for distributing code into namespaces like that (especially in case of libraries with public interface)?

Comment: I usually see it for code that's not meant to be part of the interface of the library/framework. So in a sense, quite the same as `internal` I'd say.

Comment: If it's an implementation detail then name doesn't matter at all if you're consistent across your library (and this will help you, not your library users). As you don't care (from an outside point of view) how private variables are named (in fact there are tons of _conventions_ for that). `detail`, `internal`, `implementation`, `impl`, `core`...what you want.

Comment: "Is there any common convention?" Yes - choose a name that expresses the intention of "internal detail". Like `internal`, or `detail`. Or `privates`, `gubbins`, `malarkey`, ...

Comment: I usually name private stuff with a trailing underscore. For this reason, I like `impl_` as the name of the namespace storing implementation details that must be declared/defined in headers. The intent should be quite clear to users, and it's even one character shorter than `detail`.

Comment: @BorisDalstein If you use the Pimpl idiom, then an `impl_` namespace might be confusing if you have a private member variable named `impl_`.

Comment: @EmileCormier Good point. I haven't come across such name conflicts yet, but it's something to consider.

Comment: I'm finding myself wanting to use `guts` as a shorter synonym for `detail` or `internal`, especially since I'm an 80 column guy.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A namespace called `detail` is typically used in just the same way as a namespace called `internal`. It's for "internal details" that are not visible in the public interface or which, at least, should be ignored by external users.