# limit scope of template function to a header file

Tags: c++, templates

I have some template functions implemented in a header file and I would like to limit their scope to that header file as they are only used as helper functions in that file. The unnamed namespace won't do the trick because when the header file is included in another file to use the main (non helper) functions, the helper functions become exposed. is there a solution to limit their scope?

Comment: Why not move them to the cpp ?

Comment: because they are templates?

Comment: Non paranoid solution: Give the namespace a name (maybe 'detail'). You may also put it into an extra header, to hide it little bit more.

Comment: thought about it but i was looking for actual encapsulation :)

Comment: if nobody use them, template functions won't be compiled anyway, so giving a namespace is in essence encapsulate the template function. Put it in nested namespace if you're so afraid someone else use that function by mistake. :)

Answer (score 2):

Declare the helper functions in the header file.

*Define* the helper functions **and the templates** in a source file.

Yes, you **can** put templates in a source file so long as they are not used by any other translation unit. "Templates always need to be in headers" is a myth that needs to be busted. Remember that a *compiler* compiles *source* files: the *preprocessor* generates a source file, often from header includes. Granted, it is unusual since templates are normally written with an intention of generic use and confining them to a single translation unit somewhat suffocates them.

Comment: you've got a point but with your suggestion, however the function is still public (by the declaration) and not encapsulated. So it can be included and declared in any translational unit or not? I was looking for an encapsulation solution. I guess I have to use empty classes

Comment: If the *function* contains template parameters then the templates have to be visible to any compilation unit that requires that function.

Comment: but how are template member functions encapsulated inside the class if they are private?

Comment: It's difficult to put any more flesh on the bones on a 3 sentence question with no code snippets ;-)

Comment: well, I guess based on the answers, it's either using a namespace like detail or mimic the encapsulation with empty classes are the available options. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is put the helper function into a `detail` or `internal` namespace in the header file.  [Typically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546265/what-is-the-detail-namespace-commonly-used-for) anything in those namespaces are reserved for the implementation and should not be used/relied on as they can change without notice.  It is not foolproof as there is nothing stopping the user from using them but it at least they know they are playing with fire.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a class.

Declare your templates as private static functions in the class.

Have the class `friend` the helper functions in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in class, make it private, and put other classes in current header file as friend class. Something like:

```
class Helper
{
    friend class SomeClass;
    friend class OtherClass;
    template<typename A>bool someFunc(A, int a);
    template<typename A>bool otherFunc(A);
}
```

Comment: For a drop of extra trickyness, at the end of the header do: `#define Helper` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can move the implementation to the cpp.
That will cause anyone that tries to use them (besides your own project) to fail while linking.

So in the **header** you have a forward declaration of the template function:

```
template <typenamte T> void myFunc;
```

and in the **.cpp** you got the implementation:

```
template <typenamte T> void myFunc
{

}
```