# Nested class of a template class - interoperability and visibility

Tags: c++, class, templates, types, instantiation

I have a template class `A<T>` with a [nested class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types) `Inner` - I use it to hide implementation details. I might have different instantiations of the class `A`. `A` can hold a pointer to `Inner` and I might need to do operations with those pointers within 2 different instantiations. In those cases, I might get 2 different Inner classes - `A<T1>::Inner` and `A<T2>::Inner`. From a compiler perspective, these are different types and are not compatible. A non-working example:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    template <typename T2> friend class A;

    struct Inner {
        Inner(int64_t timestamp) : timestamp(timestamp) {}
        int64_t timestamp;
    };

    Inner* inner_pointer;
    T val;

public:
    template<typename U>
    A(const A<U> other, const T& val) : inner_pointer(other.inner_pointer), val(val) {}

    A(const T& val, int64_t time_now) : inner_pointer(new Inner(time_now)), val(val) {}
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    A first('a', 123);
    A second(first, 0.2);
    return 0;
}
```

One way to get around this could be to use `reinterpret_cast<Inner*>(other.inner_pointer)`, but that's ugly, and I would guess a UB as well.

Another way is not to make `Inner` and nested class, but a separate class instead:

```
struct Inner {
    Inner(int64_t timestamp) : timestamp(timestamp) {}
    int64_t timestamp;
};

template<typename T>
class A {
    template <typename T2> friend class A;

    Inner* inner_pointer;
    T val;

public:
    template<typename U>
    A(const A<U> other, const T& val) : inner_pointer(other.inner_pointer), val(val) {}

    A(const T& val, int64_t time_now) : inner_pointer(new Inner(time_now)), val(val) {}
};
```

This solves the problem, but then it makes the `Inner` class visible to anyone who uses the `A` class since it is part of the header file that needs to be included and it also pollutes the scope.

I guess the STL implementations get around this using names that are reserved (starting with underscore). Is there a simple/elegant way how to achieve this without exposing the `Inner` class?

Comment: Making it a separate class definitely seems the correct approach. A typical approach is to put toys sort of class in an `detail` or `impl` namespace to indicate it's not intended for external use

Comment: *"it also pollutes the scope"* -- Good thought. How can you move the name to another scope? -- *"I guess the STL implementations get around this using names that are reserved"* -- That is one way. It's also something that [the `detail` namespace is commonly used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546265/what-is-the-detail-namespace-commonly-used-for)

Comment: "_and I would guess a UB as well_": Yes, absolutely.

Comment: "_and are not compatible_": Type compatibility is a C concept that isn't used in C++.

Comment: one can read it between the lines, but you never mention that you would actually like `A<T>::Inner` and `A<U>::Inner` to be the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trick based on the assumption that `A<void>` is not a valid instantiation. (If this is an artifact of simplification, there are other ways to get a similar effect.)

First, declare (not define) your template and define `A<void>` with `Inner` as a nested type.
*More generally, you could move all the common functionality, such as the `inner_pointer` member, to this specialization. This opens the possibility of moving the common code, including the definition of `Inner`, out of the header to a source file.*

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

// Declare the template.
template<typename T>
class A;

// Define A<void>
template<>
class A<void> {
    template <typename T2> friend class A;

    struct Inner {
        Inner(int64_t timestamp) : timestamp(timestamp) {}
        int64_t timestamp;
    };

    // Private constructor prevents the use outside the A template.
    A() = default;
    // Protected (or private) destructor allows safe polymorphism without virtual functions.
    ~A() = default;
};
```

Next, define your general template, using `A<void>` as a base type.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class A : private A<void> {
    template <typename T2> friend class A;

    Inner* inner_pointer;
    T val;

public:
    template<typename U>
    A(const A<U> other, const T& val) : inner_pointer(other.inner_pointer), val(val) {}

    A(const T& val, int64_t time_now) : inner_pointer(new Inner(time_now)), val(val) {}
};
```

All your template instantiations now use the same `Inner` type.

The drawback of this is that we have not really changed the problem; the `A<void>` type is visible to anyone who uses the `A` template. However, it is not usable (since everything is private), and we have eliminated the namespace pollution as there is not a new identifier introduced.